# Inserting a manual page-break in a pdf document - PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf, page-break

I have 3 arrays ($PSA, $NP and $OP) which I use to generate a pdf. The function I use to generate the pdf is given below. The problem is, all the values in the arrays cannot be contained in one page so there is a need to add page breaks, but when i try to SetAutoPageBreak to TRUE the pdf fail to load. When it is set to False (like in the method) I get only the first page of values(rest is cut-off). Is there a way to manually set page breaks? I could use a condition like:
`if($pdf->getPageHeight()-$GetY() < 5)  add a page break;`
but not sure where to put the code (I'd have to check for the condition before each line is output??)
Thank You!

```
function generate_pvr($PSA, $NP, $OP, $FROM, $TO){
        $heading = 'Test [ From: '.$FROM.' To: '.$TO.' ]';
        $border = 0;

        $pdf = new TTPDF('P','mm','A4');
        $pdf->setMargins(0,0);
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE);
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $adjust_x = 0;
        $adjust_y = 0;

        //Heading
        $pdf->SetFont('','B',12);
        $pdf->setXY( Misc::AdjustXY(30, $adjust_x), Misc::AdjustXY(20, $adjust_y) );
        $pdf->Cell(30,15,$heading, $border, 0);

        $block_adjust_y = 45;
        $block_adjust_x = 40;

        //PA entries
        foreach( $PSA as $key=>$value ) {             
            $block_adjust_y = $block_adjust_y + 5;
            $pdf->setXY( Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_x, $adjust_x), Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_y, $adjust_y) );
            $pdf->SetFont('','B',12);
            $pdf->Cell(45,5, $key, $border, 0, 'L');
            $pdf->setXY( Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_x + 20, $adjust_x), Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_y + 10, $adjust_y) );
            $pdf->SetFont('','I',10);
            $pdf->Cell(45,5, 'Emp#', $border, 0, 'L');
            $pdf->Cell(45,5, 'Employee Name', $border, 0, 'L');
            $pdf->Cell(45,5, 'Amount', $border, 0, 'R');
            $block_adjust_y = $block_adjust_y + 15;

            foreach ($value as $key2=>$value2){
                        $pdf->setXY( Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_x+20, $adjust_x), Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_y + 5, $adjust_y) );
                        $pdf->SetFont('','',10);
                        $pdf->Cell(45,5, $value2['emp_num'], $border, 0, 'L');
                        $pdf->Cell(45,5, $value2['user_name'], $border, 0, 'L');
                        $pdf->Cell(45,5, TTi18n::formatNumber( $value2['amount'] ), $border, 0, 'R');
                        $sumpsa = $sumpsa + $value2['amount'];
                        $block_adjust_y = $block_adjust_y + 5;



            }
            $pdf->setXY( Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_x+20, $adjust_x), Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_y + 5, $adjust_y) );
            $pdf->SetFont('','B',10);
            $pdf->Cell(90,5, 'Total', $border, 0, 'C');
            $pdf->Cell(45,5, TTi18n::formatNumber( $sumpsa ), $border, 0, 'R');
            $sumpsa = 0;
            $block_adjust_y = $block_adjust_y + 10;


    }


        //NP entries
        $pdf->setXY( Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_x, $adjust_x), Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_y + 5, $adjust_y) );
        $pdf->SetFont('','B',12);
        $pdf->Cell(45,5, 'NP', $border, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->setXY( Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_x + 20, $adjust_x), Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_y + 15, $adjust_y) );
        $pdf->SetFont('','I',10);
        $pdf->Cell(45,5, 'Emp#', $border, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Cell(45,5, 'Employee Name', $border, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Cell(45,5, 'Amount', $border, 0, 'R');
        $block_adjust_y = $block_adjust_y + 15;
        foreach ($NP as $keynp => $valuenp){
            $pdf->setXY( Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_x+20, $adjust_x), Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_y + 10, $adjust_y) );
            $pdf->SetFont('','',10);
            $pdf->Cell(45,5, $valuenp['employee_number'], $border, 0, 'L');
            $pdf->Cell(45,5, $valuenp['user_name'], $border, 0, 'L');
            $pdf->Cell(45,5, TTi18n::formatNumber( $valuenp['amount'] ), $border, 0, 'R');
            $sum_nopay = $sum_nopay + $valuenp['amount'];
            $block_adjust_y = $block_adjust_y + 5;
        }
        $pdf->setXY( Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_x+20, $adjust_x), Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_y + 10, $adjust_y) );
        $pdf->SetFont('','B',10);
        $pdf->Cell(90,5, 'Variation Total', $border, 0, 'C');
        $pdf->Cell(45,5, TTi18n::formatNumber( $sum_nopay ), $border, 0, 'R');
        $sum_nopay = 0;
        $block_adjust_y = $block_adjust_y + 10;

        //OP entries
        $pdf->setXY( Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_x, $adjust_x), Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_y + 5, $adjust_y) );
        $pdf->SetFont('','B',12);
        $pdf->Cell(45,5, 'Over Pay', $border, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->setXY( Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_x + 20, $adjust_x), Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_y + 15, $adjust_y) );
        $pdf->SetFont('','I',10);
        $pdf->Cell(45,5, 'Emp#', $border, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Cell(45,5, 'Employee Name', $border, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Cell(45,5, 'Amount', $border, 0, 'R');
        $block_adjust_y = $block_adjust_y + 15;
        foreach ($OP as $keyop => $valueop){
            $pdf->setXY( Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_x+20, $adjust_x), Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_y + 10, $adjust_y) );
            $pdf->SetFont('','',10);
            $pdf->Cell(45,5, $valueop['employee_number'], $border, 0, 'L');
            $pdf->Cell(45,5, $valueop['user_name'], $border, 0, 'L');
            $pdf->Cell(45,5, TTi18n::formatNumber( $valueop['amount'] ), $border, 0, 'R');
            $sum_overpay = $sum_overpay + $valueop['amount'];
            $block_adjust_y = $block_adjust_y + 5;
        }
        $pdf->setXY( Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_x+20, $adjust_x), Misc::AdjustXY($block_adjust_y + 10, $adjust_y) );
        $pdf->SetFont('','B',10);
        $pdf->Cell(90,5, 'Variation Total', $border, 0, 'C');
        $pdf->Cell(45,5, TTi18n::formatNumber( $sum_overpay ), $border, 0, 'R');
        $sum_overpay = 0;
        $block_adjust_y = $block_adjust_y + 10;            

        return $pdf->Output('','S');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code to add a page.

```
$pdf->AddPage();
```

After using the above code, succeeding calls to the FPDF class would be rendered in the new page.

Comment: `$pdf->AddPage();`  Tried it. It only adds a new page, but the excess lines are not shown in the new page. New page remains blank.

Comment: you can use addPage() for manual page break on the first page (before the content that goes to the following page) then use it again after the page. i saw your code and the manual use of getY and getPageHeight(), you can use it to determine where you are in the PDF and adjust it to go to the next page accordingly

Comment: Thanks. It did Work. For anyone interested  `if($pdf->getPageHeight() - $pdf->GetY() < 20){  //Add footer for this page  //Add new page  //Add header for new page  }`  you will have to put the condition before printing a new line